# Is DXA 2.0 compatible with the latest version of the .NET Framework?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

The DXA 2.0 [documentation](https://bit.ly/2UUH8XX) states Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 as a prerequisite, it does not state "or later", as with the Java version.

We would like to use the latest .Net Framework version, 4.7.2 at time of writing. We installed .Net Framework 4.7.2 (and the equivalent developer pack) then configured our Visual Studio project to use 4.7.2. The solution builds correctly and our site runs as expected.

Is this enough to ensure that DXA will run on 4.7.2? and if so, are there any implications to gaining support if we're not of the version specified in the documentation?

Comment: Have you considered using DXA 2.1, which is built and tested against .NET 4.6.2 ?

Comment: Thanks Rick, We're on SDL Web 8.5 (CM + CD) so I believe DXA 2.0 is the highest we can go without upgrading, at least the CM.

Comment: That’s correct.  DXA 2.2 will support SDL Web 8.5 again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the latest version no one can stop you. As far as I can see, even DXA 2.1 is supported only for .NET Framework 4.6.2 according to this [link.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v11&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8B8C6D9E-365E-4C2D-90FD-C4BDFA8B12B2.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659) What this means for you? Well probably you won't loose support for it, but every issue you occur in your app, for you to have a customer support, **you must reproduce the issue in 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2.**

But please, contact customer support, ask them for definite answer, and they will most probably provide you with one.

Comment: Indeed, it is not feasible for SDL to test/certify all versions of DXA against all version of the .NET Framework (note that “the latest version” is a moving target).

Comment: Also note that DXA is built on CIL, so you should also respect the platform support of that: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-4C8490C8-2476-4E0D-BF73-F0274E2ED772